# How to use Sikuli for Android testing?

Tags: android, testing, sikuli

I am testing an Android application with Sikuli, but each time the test runs the behaviour is different:

- the test stops at the first command, not finding the first image
- finds only some images and the test stops at a particular image which isn't found
- finds all images and the test runs successfully

[image: Here is the example test and one of its behaviour when running it.]

Sikuli is runned on Windows 7. Does anyone know if it's a problem of focus or something else and how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can fix your recognition issue by changing the matching level. From Sikuli Gui :

- Click on the image
- In Pattern Settings > Matching Preview, drag the Similarity bar to a value below 1.0 (try different values)

Comment: Sometimes no matter how I set the matching value, it still doesn't find the image. It happens to find it in Matching Preview and not finding it when running the test or even not finding it in Matching Preview.

Comment: did you find a fix for this @blavi

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to add a delay for the browse button to appear on the screen.  You could try something like this

```
wait("Browse.png", 10 )  # Wait for up to 10s for the app to load
```

You might also try increasing the size of the picture that you are matching to.  Try including nearby artifacts.  Remember that you can change the location on the picture that is the mouse click point if your Browse button is not dead centre.

Comment: The test fails at wait as well, not finding the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try any click action twice, using a try/except block.
Sometimes the vision algorithm just fails.

Answer (score 0):

Running the Android Emulator (for anything) is paaaainffullly sloooow and arbitrary.

So, it pays with Android ems to make Sikuli statements a little "smarter,"
like this:

wait(browsebutton.png, 20)

onAppear(browsebutton.png, click(browsebutton.png))

Looks busier, but it makes the script "smart" in both waiting for the button, and then clicking it as soon as it appears (instead of waiting twenty seconds if it appears after five).